# Atribute saperetes from bracket in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, brackets

Attribute separates from the bracket. Here is a printscreen and in the red foursquare you can see how attribute is in the new line from the bracket.

[image]

I have uninstalled extension "bracket pair colorizer"

Comment: bracket pair colorizer has nothing to do with this, bracket pair colorizer is now build in, it is a formatter problem/setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- May be you can try this, it may work:
  Go to `Settings` > `Wrap Attributes` ( In the search bar type *Wrap Attributes* ) and in the `HTML Format` make that to *Auto* if it isn't.
- If that doesn't try installing extension called *Prettier - Code formatter* and check whether it can solve your issue.

Comment: it is due to some extension he has installed, so better to disable them and see that it fixes the problem, I have no formatter installed and do not have this problem, just disable `format on save`

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your answers, I found the solution. It was a problem with an extension. 

thank you again :))